# Master Page location of controls in content page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm trying to rebuild a site using masterpages.  I copied the markup of the controls in the old page and placed them in the content place holder in the new page(in source view).

Since they were absolutely positioned the controls do not stay inside the content place holder in design view.  Everything is between the content place holder tags in source view.

the page works when I run it.  Is there anything wrong in leaving it like this?  I can't seem to drag all the controls into the content placeholder in design view.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I very rarely use the design view. It is much easier and faster to just type it out by hand and by doing so you become more accustomed to the language. As for old content you can just paste it into the source and it should work fine barring mistakes in the old content of course. The Design View is not always going to accurately display your code so I would not worry too much about. You should try to build the page and make sure there are not any small discrepancies though.

Answer (score 0):

Since the design view is simply a GUI representation of the code, if the code is right, then you should be fine.  As far as user experience goes, I'd be a little worried, though.  Was there an actual question, or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't really have a problem there. Get back to coding and have fun! ***grins*

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I've ever heard of someone using the Design view in Visual Studio. :)

The code is the master... if the code is between the content tags, then it's in the placeholder.

It would be nice if there was a way to just completely turn off the Design pane, because it's pretty much worthless.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem for years.  And yes, I know, "always use the source view" and "programmers should just write the code."  But there are times when you just want to drag a control from the toolbox and plop it on the page in design view or link a control to a datasource without typing everything out.

So, definite flaw in VS.  Design View is almost unusable when using Master Pages & Content Place Holders.